# How to stop banner add overlaying navigation drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, drawer

I am new to flutter in my app i am using navigation drawer and admin banner ads.but the banner ad is overlaying drawer when drawer is opened.how to make the banner ad stay behind the drawer.

Comment: You can use admob widget in "bottomNavigationBar".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using official admob plugin [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) so the banner ad overlays all your flutter widgets.

So instead use [admob_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter) plugin to display your ads, that way your ads will stay behind the drawer.